# Binding in List with XML

Tags: json, xml, binding, model, sapui5

I want to use only XML to bind a list to the data of a JSON file.

Here is my code:

XML View:

```
<List
    headerText="Positions"
    items="{/Positions}">
    <ObjectListItem
        title="{positions>id}">
    </ObjectListItem>
</List>
```

index.html

```
var oPositionsModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
oPositionsModel.loadData("model/Positions.json");
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oPositionsModel);
```

model/Positions.json

```
{
"Positions": [
    {
        "id": 123456,
        "article": "Abcde",
        "amount": 12
    },
    {
        "id": 654321,
        "article": "Edcba",
        "amount": 21
    }
]
}
```

I can't see, what's wrong. But I get "no data" all the time.
There is nothing in the console saying there is a problem here.

Comment: Is the data loaded correctly from the server?

Comment: the get request on Positions.json I get a Response with 200 Ok status

Comment: also tryed: <Label text="{/Positions}"/> and Positions.json: {"Positions": "hey"}. Isn't working. So it's not the <List>, the problem is with the binding

Comment: I used your code (but fixed the faulty `ObjectListItem` title binding), and it just works : http://plnkr.co/edit/1Zx0aLExiCKhGwTv85yU?p=preview so there must be something else wrong

Comment: The List shall be bound against an array. If your JSON-File contains {"Positions": "hey"} it cannot work!

Comment: I changed the list with a Label for simplification. My bad to not make that clear.

Comment: Made a new project in my WebIDE. Created a JSON with {"text": "hello"}. Set the Model to the core. In the App.view.xml I inserted <Label text="{/text}"/>
Is there something more I need to do?
I cann't get even this simple example working.

Comment: How do you start UI5? Does the script tag contain the attribute data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"?

Comment: That's my bootstrap after inserting "bindingSyntax":
  <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
   src="../../resources/sap-ui-core.js"
   data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
   data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
   data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
   data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax="complex"
   data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"ReviewOrders": ""}'>
  </script>
Same result.

Comment: See the Plunker demo I posted in the comments; does your WebIDE project resemble this structure?

Comment: At debugging I did: sap.ui.getCore().getModel() and got the Model object with the loaded array in oData.

Comment: @qualiture: beside the thing that I don't have a formatter. Everything is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your binding for the `title` attribute is not correct. You want to bind it directly to the `id` attribute of `Positions`, no need to specify the model:

```
<List
    headerText="Positions"
    items="{/Positions}">
    <ObjectListItem
        title="{id}">
    </ObjectListItem>
</List>
```

[Working demo in JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ruguya/edit?html,output)

Comment: He mentions that the no-data information is shown, i.e. the binding of the item aggreation does not work. However you are right with the title attribute binding, but this does not result in a no-data-information.

Comment: I changed it. But same result. I get "no data"-information. As matbtt says. For me it seems like the <List items="{/Positions}"> binding is not working